# JAX-RS Struts2 REST API

Tags: rest, struts2, jersey, jax-rs, struts

Why would one like to integrate JAX-RS(Jersey) using Rest API to Struts2? Struts2 is itself a mvc framework, so why would anyone want to integrate these both? If combined, how will the resulting framework be(I wanted to know if REST API just control the controller part of MVC).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a RESTful plugin called `struts2-rest-plugin` that has been included with the framework since version 2.1.1. A fair amount of information on the plugin can be found [here](http://struts.apache.org/docs/rest-plugin.html).

Essentially, the plugin uses a custom action mapper that examines the request and based upon the HTTP Method used in conjunction with the URI, it dispatches the request to one of several different method names (e.g. GET /movies dispatched to index() method of action).

Just because Struts2 is an action-based framework does not mean a RESTful solution cannot be included as an alternative for developers.  Spring MVC offers similar solutions themselves and it is also an action-based framework.

If you consider your JSON response as your view, you'll see that the fact that Struts2 is based on MVC design makes logical sense.  Your model is simply the data structure you are returning to the client and your controller is the action.

Consider reading the link above on the plugin and you'll get a better picture of how the two can be integrated.  If you want to return JSON but don't necessarily want to offer RESTful URLs in your Struts2 application, you can also consider the JSON plugin, found [here](http://struts.apache.org/docs/json-plugin.html).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about Struts2, but in the past Struts1 did not have a "Rest" adapter built in. Jersey provides the cool @annotations that will easily serialize your datamodel and will push you in a "Restful" direction. Jersey does not provide an MVC framework as much as it provides convenience methods to work in a Restful/resource based way.